# jquery filter an option that has attribute "selected"

Tags: jquery, filter, selected

I have tried to use `.filter('[selected]')` but it does not work:

```
> options
[
<option label value data-parent=​"VUT" style=​"display:​ inline;​ ">​</option>​
, 
<option label=​"Fakulta architektury" value=​"architektury" data-parent=​"VUT" style=​"display:​ inline;​ ">​Fakulta architektury​</option>​
, 
<option label=​"Fakulta elektrotechniky" value=​"elektrotechniky" selected=​"selected" data-parent=​"VUT" style=​"display:​ inline;​ ">​Fakulta elektrotechniky</option>​
]

> options.filter('[selected]')
[
<option label value data-parent=​"VUT" style=​"display:​ inline;​ ">​</option>​
]
```

How can I get the option with "selected" attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Use [:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector

```
options.filter(':selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the reverse of filter: `.not('[selected]')`. I'm assuming you **don't** want those with `selected` by "filter out".

And just in case it wasn't a typo, `.filter('[selected'])` will not work simply because it contains syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
var opts = $('select option').filter(function() {
    return this.selected;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6FMZY/456/)**

**OR**

```
var opts = $('select option[selected]');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6FMZY/458/)**

Comment: @clime see the demo and console, I think you will find you option with `selected` attribute

Comment: your example works. Strangely on my options jquery object the result is the same as with .filter('[selected]').

Comment: @clime I've set another demo for you, check that